# How to prevent web view activity from starting when there is no Internet connection?

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app with a web view which loads in the second activity. The app has two activities. The second activity starts when a button is pressed in the first activity.

My problem is, I want to prevent the second activity to start and remain on the first activity and show a toast if there is no Internet connection. My network check is done in the second activity.

This is my first activity:

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void startSecondActivity(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

And this is my second activity:

```
public class SecondActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_second);

        if (!SecondActivity.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
            mWebView.setWebViewClient(new CustomWebViewClient());
            mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
            mWebView.loadUrl("http://m.sovran.in/index.php?id=" + token);
        }
    }
```

Comment: why don't you add the internetChecking code block into First Activity ? This is the basic. To insure resource before starting a new activity.

Comment: @Godslave But if I add the internet check in my first activity then there is a bigger problem, i.e., if internet goes down after user starts the second activity

Comment: thanks everyone, I will try what all of you have mentioned

Comment: If you check the internet connection in your second activity, the internet could be down when the web view is loading the URL anyway.

Comment: @Pang, Yes I already mentioned that

Comment: I was explaining why there's no big difference whether you check it in your first or your second activity.

Comment: @Pang Ohh ok, I get it now. Thanks for informing, I'm actually new to android so it's a good help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
public class FirstActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public void startSecondActivity(View view) {
         if(checkInternetConnection(this))
         {
          Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
          startActivity(intent);
          }
         else
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

As you have commented. It seems that you need to put the checkInternetConnection in a public static class and check twice in your case ?
1. Once when starting the SecondActivityIntent 
2. While loading web view for the SecondActivity

So it would be like

```
public class HelperClass{
public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context){
// your code for checking internet as you have written
...................................................
....................................
    }
    }
```

use this in this way

just call `HelperClass.checkInternetConenction(this)`
for checking from any Activity, pass the context

//--------------------------------------
Here is how your Classe Hirarchy should be 
[image]

And here is the static class

```
package workgroundspace.gs.com.workgroundspace;

import android.content.Context;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;

/**
 * Created by godslave on 6/21/16.
 */
 public class HelperClass {

    public static boolean checkInternetConnection(Context context) {
        ConnectivityManager con_manager = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isAvailable()
                && con_manager.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected()) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```

And Here I am calling the static method for internet state checking

```
package workgroundspace.gs.com.workgroundspace;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        if(HelperClass.checkInternetConnection(this)){
            Intent goToOtherActivity = new Intent(this,OtherActivity.class);

            startActivity(goToOtherActivity);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.d("MainActivity", "no internet");
            Toast.makeText(this,"No internte coneection",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: If it helps just Acept the answer. It is a proper Thanks :-)

Comment: Thanks Godslave, the last one you mentioned is really useful and this was what I was looking for, thank you soo much.

Comment: what happened ? why do you uncheck my answer as accepted answer ? May I know ?

Comment: Can you kindly just let me know where I should call this helper class. Without the helper class the code is working but with it checkInternetConnection is showing cannot resolve method checkInternetConnection.

Comment: check now, it should do the work, I checked in my IDE

Comment: Yes it worked. Thanks for the big effort. Still having a small problem though. When I start the app, it first loads the second activity screen  first because the start Activity method is in oncreate. How do I call this class outside oncreate method so that the first activity screen is shown first.

Comment: Ok it worked, I had to change few things, thanks for the help, I will accept your answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public void startSecondActivity(View view) {
    if (!SecondActivity.checkInternetConnection(this)) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No Internet Connection!!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome hope it will help you if yes then please accept my answer thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the internet connection before you start the second `Activity`. To check your internet connectivity use the following code. Put the function inside any class in your project. This is a `public static` function that can be accessible from anywhere.

```
public static boolean isConnectionAvailable(Context context) {
    if (context == null) return false;

    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo info = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    return info != null && info.isConnected();
}
```

So now in your `FirstActivity` replace the function `startSecondActivity` with this. Note that, you don't actually need to pass the `View` in the `startSecondActivity` function.

```
public void startSecondActivity() {

    if(!isConnectionAvailable(this)) return; 

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Reaz, I will try it